# How to fetch a value from a database in a <p> tag and to post them into database with the same id

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ajax, codeigniter, angularjs-directive

I am new to angularjs and I want to make an application just like a Google keeps notes. I succeed in fetching the data inside the `<p>` tag in the list format. My condition is whenever I make any changes in the `<p>` tag, it is in the database. I tried to do this with ngKeyup() but I did not succeed so I removed `ngKeyup()`. How can I do this with the ajax jquery or javascript?

---view---

```
<ul ng-repeat="n in notes">
    <li>
        <p class="note-preview" ng-model="note_content">{{n.note_content}}</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

---js---

```
angular.module('app')
    .controller('GlobalCtrl', ['$scope','$http', function($scope,$http) {

    $http.get("notes/get_notes").then(function(result) {
        $scope.notes = result.data;
        console.log($scope.notes);
    });

}]);
```

---CI Controller---

```
public function get_notes() {
    $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $userdata = $this->notes_model->get_user_note($user_id);
    echo json_encode($notedata);
}
```

---CI Model---

```
public function get_user_note($user_id) {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $query = $this->db->get_where('note', array('employee_id' => $user_id));
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Comment: where you use ngKeyup()?

Answer (score 0):

Doing this on keyUp will not make sense unless you debounce your save function. Imagine everytime the keyboard is pressed the back-end is called, you would very soon flood the backend with ajax requests.

Have a look at [angular-debounce](https://github.com/rubenv/angular-debounce), you could then use a $watch on the notes array to run the save function.